# Getting error in steppers

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

`StepFragmentSample.java`:

```
public class StepFragmentSample extends Fragment implements Step {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step, container, false);
        //initialize your UI
        return v;
    }

    public VerificationError verifyStep() {
        //return null if the user can go to the next step, create a new VerificationError instance otherwise
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelected() {
        //update UI when selected
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull VerificationError error) {
        //handle error inside of the fragment, e.g. show error on EditText
    }
}
```

`MyStepAdapter.java`:

```
public static class MyStepperAdapter extends AbstractFragmentStepAdapter {
    public MyStepperAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm, context);
    }

    @Override
    public Step createStep(int position) {
        final StepFragmentSample step = new StepFragmentSample();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY, position);
        step.setArguments(b);
        return step;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StepViewModel getViewModel(@IntRange(from = 0) int position) {
        //Override this method to set Step title for the Tabs, not necessary for other stepper types
        return new StepViewModel.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(R.string.tab_title) //can be a CharSequence instead       
            .create();
    }
}
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class StepperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private StepperLayout mStepperLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mStepperLayout = (StepperLayout) findViewById(R.id.stepperLayout);
        mStepperLayout.setAdapter(new MyStepperAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));
    }
```

[I have copied the above code from this link.](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper)}

While debugging, the control does not goes to `createStep` Method In `StepFragmentSample.java`

while debugging from `mainActivity.java`, the control goes to `MyStepAdapter.java` in that first `MyStepperAdapter()` method then to `getCount()` method but not to `createStep()`. why? please help me. and It does not giving any exception. The app shows "unfortunately stopped".

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: I made changes to the question.Once check and give me the solution sir.@NaveenKumarM